# Are all slow-varying functions slower than all polynomials?

Tags: calculus, limits, asymptotics

I'm wondering if all increasing slow varying functions are slower than all powers of x. It is easy to show that all positive powers of x are not slow varying but I'm wondering if it is possible to show that if for all positive real k and some arbitrary increasing function f $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^k}{f(x)}=\infty$ would imply $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(ax)}{f(x)}=1$.

Comment: If $f(x)=\frac1x$, then $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^k}{f(x)}=\infty$ for all $k>0$ but $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(ax)}{f(x)}=\frac1a$.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I meant to restrict it to increasing functions.

Comment: "all positive real k" or all natural k?

Comment: @AkshatSharma All real k, so including (0,1).

Comment: You need some regularity assumption stronger than just the increase. Otherwise there are counterexamples such as $f(x)=e^{\lfloor\log\log x\rfloor}$ (and no, requiring continuity is not a remedy).

Comment: @metamorphy what would a counterexample be in the case of a continuous function? Also wouldn't that still be slowly-varying.